# Creating a decent PDF/A document

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, pdf-a

Let's say I have a simple document having some sections and Unicode and/or math in their titles. How to produce a decent PDF output? By that I mean:

- It contains correct metadata.
- It contains correct bookmarks.
- It is a PDF/A document.

I have produced the following example. (I know that it may not be a good idea to have that much math and Unicode in titles, but to some extent it's ok, and the source below is just an example.)

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.xmpdata}
\Title{Properties of ℝ^ω} 
\Author{Foo Barovič\sep Baz Pequeño} 
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nomath]{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[a-2u]{pdfx}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{
    \def\omega{ω}
}
\begin{document}
    \title{Properties of $\mathbb{R}^\omega$}
    \author{Foo Barovič, Baz Pequeño}
    \date{}
    \maketitle

    \section{\texorpdfstring
            {Basic properties of $\mathbb{R}^\omega$}
            {Basic properties of ℝ\textasciicircumω}
        }
        Here we shall talk about the basic properties.

        \subsection{\texorpdfstring
                {$\mathbb{R}^\omega$ vs.\ $\bigcup_{n \in \omega} \mathbb{R}^n$ according to Pequeño}
                {ℝ\textasciicircumω vs. ⋃\_\{n ∈ ω\} ℝ\textasciicircum n according to Pequeño}
            }
            A short note about this inductive limit approach.

    \section{\texorpdfstring
            {Advanced properties of $\mathbb{R}^\omega$}
            {Advanced properties of ℝ\textasciicircum\omega}
        }
        Here we shall talk about the advanced properties.

\end{document}
```

What still annoys me:

- The duplicities in titles. It is possible to map a Unicode character to a macro via the `inputenc` package. For PDF bookmarks the situation is opposite: it is possible to map macros to Unicode characters using `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands`. This works well for `\omega` or `\bigcup`, but what to do with superscripts, subscripts, groups, `$`, and `\mathbb{R}`? Is there a way to declare that `^`, `_`, `{`, `}` should be taken literally, `$` should be ignored, and `\mathbb{R}` means ℝ? Then, `\texorpdfstring` won't be needed.
- The duplicities in the main title and authors.
- The fact that `filecontents*` does not rewrite existing document. I know this can be changed by `filecontents` package, but it still emits a warning, and it cannot be loaded before `\documentclass`, while generating of xmpdata is recommended before `\documentclass`.

I'd be glad for any tips or tricks in improving the given source.

Comment: Use [ConTeXt MKIV](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/PDF/A).